# FaceTime activation

Tags: facetime

I just downloaded FaceTime. For some unknown reasons, it was activated 4 times, and I was billed 4 times for the activation SMS. Are there any ways to get money back? I don't have Apple store or official support in my country.

Comment: What country are you based in?

Comment: It is generally not possible to get refund for the SMS sent for activation.